# How do I fix Apple Music "Cloud Music Library is not responding"?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music

After [Apple System Status](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) showed an iTunes outage today, my iCloud Music Library in Apple Music stopped working on my Mac. I saw the following dialog repeatedly:

[image: Dialog reading "The shared library 'Cloud Music Library' is not responding. (503)"]

I have no control over the firewalls in Cupertino , so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After wrestling with this all day, even after iTunes status showed normal, I found [this solution](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28676971#28676971):

1. Open iTunes.
2. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> to open the Preferences dialog.
3. Uncheck **Show Apple Music**, acknowledge the dialog advising you you will stop using iCloud Music Library, then select **OK**.
4. Reopen the Preferences dialog.
5. Check **Show Apple Music** again as well as **iCloud Music Library**, then select **OK**.

This will restore iCloud Music Library.  Note: I could not immediately add music to my library after this without seeing more errors, but the next morning I found my add attempt had succeeded and everything seems to be in good shape.

Comment: When you finish step 3 does iTunes commence deleting all the music you downloaded to that Mac?

Comment: @bmike I don't download music to my Mac—only stream it—so I don't know the answer to that question.

Comment: aah. So you wouldn't be looking at the storage caches or the local downloads then. Thanks!